# React JS: Component not updating, after calling setState

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

I've got a small react app I'm playing with, just go get the hang of the library.  The app is just a series of lists, which are populated from a server.  When a list item is clicked, the value of that item is added to a list filters at the app level, which will then be used to call new data to populate the lists.

The problem is that I can't seem to get my lists to reconcile with the new data from the app (parent), even when calling `setState`.  Here's my code (coffee):

```
### 
@jsx React.DOM
###

{div, h1, h2, h4, ul, li, form, input, br, p, strong, span, a} = React.DOM

SearchApp = React.createClass
  handleTopItemClick: (filter) ->
    facet = filter.field
    filters = @state.filters
    if filters.facets[facet] and filters.facets[facet].length > 0
      filters.facets[facet].push filter.value
    else 
      filters.facets[facet] = [filter.value]

    strArr = []
    _.each filters.facets, (valArr, field) ->
      _.each valArr, (val) ->
        strArr.push "+(#{field}:\"#{val}\")" 

    @setState 
      filters: filters
      queryStr: strArr.join(' ').trim()

  getInitialState: ->
    filters:
      facets: {}
    queryStr: ''    

  render: ->
    (div {
      id: 'content'
      className: "search-wrap"
      },
      (h1 {}, "Search")
      (div
        id: 'widgets',
        (TopList
          title: 'Top Domains'
          params:
            query: @state.queryStr
            field: 'domain'
          onItemClick: @handleTopItemClick
        )
        (TopList
          title: 'Top Senders'
          params:
            query: @state.queryStr
            field: 'from'
          onItemClick: @handleTopItemClick
        )
        (TopList
          title: 'Top Recipient'
          params:
            query: @state.queryStr
            field: 'recipient'
          onItemClick: @handleTopItemClick
        ) 
      )        
    )

TopItem = React.createClass
  getDefaultProps: ->
    value: ''
    count: 0
    field: null

  render: ->
    (li {},
      (a {
        onClick: @handleClick
        className: 'top-item-filter'
        title: @props.value
        },
        (strong {}, @props.value)
        (span {}, @props.count)
      )
    )

  handleClick: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    @props.onItemClick @props.value

TopList = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    data: []
    params: @props.params

  componentWillReceiveProps: (nextProps) ->
    @setState params: nextProps.params

  componentWillMount: ->
    request.post("/facet").send(@state.params).end (results) =>
      @setState data: JSON.parse(results.text)

  render: ->
    itemNodes = _.map @state.data, (item) =>
      key = item.value
      TopItem
        value: item.value
        count: item.count
        key: key
        onItemClick: @handleItemClick

    (div {className: 'widget top-item'},
      (h2 {className: 'widget-header'}, "#{@props.title}")
      (ul {className: 'top-items-list'}, itemNodes)
    )

  handleItemClick: (value) ->
    @props.onItemClick
      value: value
      field: @props.params.field

React.renderComponent SearchApp(null), document.getElementById("content")
```

The lists all render fine the first time around, fetching the unfiltered data as expected.  When I click on a list item, the `SearchApp` receives the event, and updates its own state accordingly.  `componentWillReceiveProps` is properly called on the `TopList` classes, but the `setState` call there doesn't update their state, and thus, they aren't reconciling.  I've verified that `nextProps` contains the new information.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't really any reason to save the props in state; and it's much less error prone to keep props as the source of truth.  It also simplifies the code a bit.

For the actual issue, though; componentWillMount is only called once here.  If you want to repeat the AJAX request when new params are passed; you can do that like so:

```
TopList = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    data: []

  getSearchResultsFromServer: (params) ->
    request.post("/facet").send(params).end (results) =>
      if @isMounted()
        @setState data: JSON.parse(results.text) 

  componentWillReceiveProps: (nextProps) -> @getSearchResultsFromServer nextProps.params
  componentDidMount: -> @getSearchResultsFromServer @props.params

  render: ->
    itemNodes = _.map @state.data, (item) =>
      key = item.value
      TopItem
        value: item.value
        count: item.count
        key: key
        onItemClick: @handleItemClick

    (div {className: 'widget top-item'},
      (h2 {className: 'widget-header'}, "#{@props.title}")
      (ul {className: 'top-items-list'}, itemNodes)
    )

  handleItemClick: (value) ->
    @props.onItemClick
      value: value
      field: @props.params.field
```

Ideally, your ajax library would support aborting requests; and in componentWillUnmount you abort those requests.

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much! I also removed the setting of state via props, as you suggested.